# Running into DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE error with ios-sim

Tags: ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I'm trying get ionic up and running using my mac by following the simple instructions on the website (http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Everything is working until i need to emulate

`$ ionic emulate ios`

I did a little deeper and I realized the same error lies in when I tried to run `ios-sim`

Here is what I see

```
$ ios-sim start
2015-02-27 14:01:57.361 ios-sim[1810:208272] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-6274/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient/DTiPhoneSimulatorSessionConfig.m:143
Details:  (runtime) should not be nil.
Object:   <DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot>
Method:   +rootWithSimRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff44a5105f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000110abe24a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x0000000110abdc9f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000110abdf8e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000111062614 +[DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot rootWithSimRuntime:] (in DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient)
  4  0x0000000111061897 -[DTiPhoneSimulatorSessionConfig simulatedSystemRoot] (in DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient)
  5  0x000000010ebadab0 -[iPhoneSimulator launchApp:withFamily:uuid:environment:stdoutPath:stderrPath:timeout:args:] (in ios-sim)
  6  0x000000010ebaecfd -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] (in ios-sim)
  7  0x000000010ebaefbb main (in ios-sim)
  8  0x000000010ebac37c start (in ios-sim)
  9  0x0000000000000002
Abort trap: 6
```

Please advice

Comment: K, I finally figured it out. The reason is because my xcode did not have any simulators. All I have to do is go to Preference -> Downloads -> Install a Simulator

Comment: Why are you using ios-sim?  Most of that functionality is now replaced by simctl.  Is there some feature of ios-sim that is missing that you would want to see in simctl?